# Update the sitecore.configs at runtime possible?

Tags: configuration, azure

We have a requirement to store all the secrets on to azure key-vault. This requires us to update the configurations at Runtime.

One challenge we are facing at the moment is to store the password for SOLR basic auth on to azure key-vault.

```
<indexConfigurations>
        <solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="HttpWebAdapters.HttpWebRequestFactory, SolrNet">
          <patch:delete/>
        </solrHttpWebRequestFactory>
        <solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="HttpWebAdapters.BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory, SolrNet">
          <param hint="username">username</param>
          <param hint="password">password</param>
        </solrHttpWebRequestFactory>
      </indexConfigurations>
```

We managed to read and update the asp.net connection strings and web.config. However not for sitecore configs.

Question:

Is there a way (any sitecore API) which we could use to update the sitecore configurations at runtime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot update Sitecore configuration in a runtime (all configs are parsed into one big config on application start).

I would go with different approach then.

Find `HttpWebAdapters.BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory` class in **SolrNet.dll** and see how it works. 
Overwrite this class or write your own (must implement `IHttpWebRequestFactory` interface).

Inside that class, instead of taking **password** and **login** from configuration fetch it from different source (that can be changed during a runtime, the simplest case would be a **txt** file stored somewhere. Remember that the file has to be protected and cannot be accessible publicly).

Once you have your class with custom code, patch `solrHttpWebRequestFactory` node with your custom type.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize configuration by overriding the default `ConfigReader` defined in web.config. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- Insert custom ConfigReader class here -->
    <section name="sitecore" type="MyProject.CustomConfigReader, MyProject" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </configSections>
  <!-- ... -->
</configuration>
```

Then for your custom config reader, override the default one and add your patching logic after the default patching code is done:

```
namespace MyProject
{
  public class CustomConfigReader : Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigReader
  {
    protected override void LoadAutoIncludeFiles(System.Xml.XmlNode element)
    {
      base.LoadAutoIncludeFiles(element);
      PatchSolrCredentials(GetConfigPatcher(element));
    }

    protected virtual void PatchSolrCredentials(Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigPatcher patcher)
    {
      // You could also edit the XML nodes directly in patcher.Document.
      var patch = @"<configuration xmlns:patch='http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/'>
        <sitecore>
          <contentSearch>
            <indexConfigurations>
              <solrHttpWebRequestFactory>
                  <param hint='username'>username</param>
                  <param hint='password'>password</param>
              </solrHttpWebRequestFactory>
            </indexConfigurations>
          </contentSearch>
        </sitecore>
      </configuration>";
      // (Replace with username and password from key vault)
      var reader = new System.IO.StringReader(patch);
      patcher.ApplyPatch(reader);
    }
  }
}
```

Here are a couple of other interesting examples of using a custom ConfigReader:

- http://www.rockpapersitecore.com/2016/08/10/deferring-config-file-load/
- https://github.com/efocus-nl/efocus.sitecore.conditionalconfigs

Comment: Didn't work as congig reader loads begore our services ehivh gets secret from keyvault