# How to initialize Solr end point connection with basic authentication programmatically?

Tags: solr

I want to store Solr basic authentication credential in key vault and I want to achieve this by doing something like this.. however I tried using below code in application start but it seems it is not hooking properly , not sure what I m doing wrong here.

```
IHttpWebRequestFactory solrBasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory = 
    new HttpWebAdapters.BasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory("admin", "somepassword*");
solrBasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory.Create(new Uri("localhost:8080/solr"));
```

I also got one reference to patch file using this custom config reader but I m trying to work it programmatically. Any help.
[Update sitecore configs at runtime](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/update-the-sitecore-configs-at-runtime-possible/5076#5076)

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Sitecore version 8.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We created a custom BasicAuthHttpWebRequest using the reference of the code from Solr.net and then referenced this class library in solr indexconfiguration section.

```
    namespace MyclassLibrary
```

{

public class MyBasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory : IHttpWebRequestFactory
  {
    private readonly string username;
    private readonly string password;

```
public MyBasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory(string username, string password)
{//This is where we can fetch credential from appsetting
  this.username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
  this.password =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
}

public IHttpWebRequest Create(string url)
{
  return this.Create(new Uri(url));
}

public IHttpWebRequest Create(Uri url)
{
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
  string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.username + ":" + this.password));
  request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64String);
  return (IHttpWebRequest) new HttpWebRequestAdapter(request);
}
```

}
}

```
 <indexConfigurations>
    <solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="HttpWebAdapters.HttpWebRequestFactory, SolrNet">
      <patch:delete/>
    </solrHttpWebRequestFactory>
    <solrHttpWebRequestFactory type="MyClassLibrary.MyBasicAuthHttpWebRequestFactory, MyClassLibrary">
      <param hint="username">
      </param>
      <param hint="password">
      </param>
    </solrHttpWebRequestFactory>
  </indexConfigurations>
```

Comment: This isn't working - I think you're missing the configurations needed in SOLR to secure the requests.