# Enabling federated authentication using a feature flag in Code

Tags: configuration, federated-authentication

We have managed to configure our Auth0 custom identity provider in our solution. Migrating from forms authentication however will take a bit more effort than just a bunch of config.

In order to avoid a really long lived branch, would there be a possibility to switch federated security on/off using a feature switch service like Launch Darkly.

Example of config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
    <!--    This configuration disables Owin and Federated Auth which prevents Sitecore Membership Provider
            from allow website visitors to authenticate and maintain a authenticated session. 
            This only applies to Standalone used for local dev and ContentDelivery for public website. 
            The CMS will still use Sitecore Identity Server to Authenticate. -->
     <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentDelivery">
        <settings>
            <setting name="Owin.Authentication.Enabled" value="false" />
            <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.Enabled" value="false" />
        </settings>

        <sites>
            <site name="shell" set:loginPage="/sitecore/login" />
            <site name="admin" set:loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
        </sites>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Where the flags like `Owin.Authentication.Enabled` can be switched on to True at runtime by fetching this from another service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different parts to this questions:

1. Updating the `Sitecore config` at runtime is possible but hard, see [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/5062/update-the-sitecore-configs-at-runtime-possible) post for more details. However:
2. I don't believe succeeding in task 1 will actually help you. The `OWIN middleware` used by `FederatedAuthentication` gets registered when the `Application Pool` starts. The middleware is already registered if you change the setting at runtime later. This middleware cannot be removed later see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331163/4950874).

I would suggest looking into one of below approaches:

1. If the main goal is about preventing a long lived branch, then perhaps you merge and delete this branch but keep `Owin.Authentication.Enabled` disabled until you are ready to introduce this change (which will require a deployment)?
2. If above option does not work for your scenario, then you could look into the approach which is also linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331163/4950874) about wrapping the execution of the middleware with a condition. This might require a lot of customizations to Sitecore as some of the middleware is registered by Sitecore.

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful and validates some of the assumptions I had about the config initialisation. We'll just have to have different config transformations for our staging environment.